# Can't upload image using Laravel and Spatie media library run by Laragon

Tags: laravel, laragon, laravel-medialibrary

I've been having this issue 3 days now.
I already tried setting permission to full access to storage directory on windows explorer, run command `chmod -R o+w storage` but still no luck. On the other hand in my friend's dev environment using Homestead, no permission problem occurred.

**Error Message**
[image]

Comment: What web server are you running?

Comment: Looks like you are on windows from the paths, so `chmod` won't work.

Comment: @atymic yes windows.

Comment: > What web server are you running?

Comment: @atymic I'm using nginx

Comment: The directory separator after medialibrary in the path is incorrect. May I know how you are trying to store the file?

Comment: @Ravi, I believe spatie automatically generates that path.

Comment: Can you share the snippet of file upload that is causing this error?